# Catch 404 from multiple proxied requests in Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, error-handling, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm using Nginx 1.10.3 on Debian Jessie running a self deployed application with the following setup.

Loadbalancer config:

```
upstream www {
    server [fda4::0:21]:8080 weight=80;
    server [fda4::0:22]:8080 weight=100;
    keepalive 100;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/+$ /$1 permanent;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://www;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;
    }
}
```

Backend config:

```
server {
    listen [::]:8080 default_server backlog=1024;
    root /var/www/$host/web;
    index index.php;

    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    location ~ ^/index\.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
    }
}
```

We have a project `new-app` based on this setup where content from an old CMS (call it `old-app`) should be served until migration is done. My considerations are:

- When an URL is requested in `new-app` which does not exists, we want to look if `old-app` has content for it, so `new-app` throws an 404
- Nginx catches this 404 and proxies request to `old-app`
- When there is content in `old-app` it should be served along with an 2xx/3xx response code
- If there no content in `old-app` also, an additional 404 is thrown
- This 404 should be catched by Nginx again and a static error page inside `new-app` should be served

Can this be done with Nginx? I think with

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;
error_page 404 = @404;
location @404 {
    proxy_pass http://old-app.domain;
}
```

one could do the trick, but when `old-app` throws a 404 also, won't this initiate an endless loop of catch-and-proxy? What does a clean solution look like to catch a 404 in `old-app` backend for serving static error page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you always want to server `new-app` first unless there is an error, you can do this with two location blocks:

```
upstream new-app {
    server [fda4::0:21]:8080 weight=80;
    server [fda4::0:22]:8080 weight=100;
    keepalive 100;
}

upstream old-app {
    server [fda4::0:21]:8081 weight=80;
    server [fda4::0:22]:8081 weight=100;
    keepalive 100;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    recursive_error_pages on;

    location @old-app {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/+$ /$1 permanent;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://old-app;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/+$ /$1 permanent;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://new-app;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 404 = @old-app;
    }
}
```

Comment: And when I want to let `new-app` handle 404 exceptions from `old-app` I've just to add an additional `error_page` directive inside `location @old-app`?

Comment: Correct, intercept errors and add an `error_page` directive.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll give this a try this week and give feedback in next days.

Comment: Ok, after some fails I've found https://serverfault.com/a/537271/112351 which suggest to enable `recursive_error_pages on;`. After doing that on a `server` base, all is fine now. So add this to your answer, else multiple `error_page` directives will not work, and I'll accept it as correct answer.

Comment: @rabudde I've added it